# How to increment value inside txt file cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, html

i am creating a .txt file output "data.txt". Inside the file, I want to set an increment value each time the user selects a specific button. 
For example, if the user clicks on "Vote John"..
First time, "John, 1"
Second time, "John, 2"

However, my value is not incrementing by itself. Please advise. Thanks.

```js
@{
    var result = "";
    int countJohn = 1;

    if (IsPost)
    {
        if (Request["submit"] == "Vote Harry")
        {

            //var harry = Request["Harry"];

            int countHarry = 1;

            var userData = "Harry" + "," + countHarry + Environment.NewLine;

            var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/data.txt");

            File.AppendAllText(@dataFile, userData);

           // countHarry += countHarry;  does not increases the count inside  .txt at all

            result = "Information saved.";
        }

        else if (Request["submit"] == "Vote John")
        {

            //var john = Request["John"];

            var userData = "John" + "," + (Int32.Parse("1")) + Environment.NewLine;

            var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/data.txt");

            File.AppendAllText(@dataFile, userData);

            result = "Information saved.";

            countJohn += 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Elections</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Harry</td>
                    <td><input id="Harry" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Harry"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td><input id="John" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote John" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bryan</td>
                    <td><input id="Bryan" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Bryan" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jack</td>
                    <td><input id="Jack" name="submit" type="submit" value="Vote Jack" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if (result != "")
            {
                <p>Result: @result</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you ever reading from the file? It seems like you're just writing 1 every time.

Comment: `var userData = "John" + "," + (Int32.Parse("1")) + Environment.NewLine;` => this writes 1 for every count. You should read the file in specific line to get vote count, then increment it and write the file again.

Comment: where should i read the file? right after (IsPost) or inside each individual person "if else"?